# Concatenating each string in a list to several other strings in Python

Tags: python

I have a loop script that makes a list of strings from a file using the `line.split()` function, although I want to tag each string with two other strings that form during the loop.

How can I concatenate each string formed from the `line.split()` function to two other strings?

This is the relevant part of my code

```
out = str()

for fileName in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):

if line.startswith('Group:'):
    y = line.split()
    t_group = y[]
    group = t_group

if line.startswith("F:"):
   y = line.split()
   #this is where the list of strings is formed

   t_out = group + "    " + ___ # The underscores are a placeholder for each string in the list that I want to add
   out.append(t_out)
```

Comment: where has been defined `line`?

Comment: hey, Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Yes so it should be group + \t + single string from the line.split()

Comment: and each new string (consisting of one of the strings from the line.split() and the group) would be appended to out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate all strings in a list, use [join](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
strs = ["hey", "what's", "up"]
concat = "".join(strs)
print(concat)

# output
heywhat'sup
```

To append one string at a time, you could do something like:

```
output_string = "prepended text"
for string in strs:
    output_string += string
    print(output_string)
```

printed output would be:

```
prepended text
prepended texthey
prepended textheywhat's
prepended textheywhat'sup
```

Of course, you could add a space into the string each time you append your string from the list too.

```
output_string += f" {string}"
```

which would print:

```
prepended text
prepended text hey
prepended text hey what's
prepended text hey what's up
```

Comment: I do not want to use all of the strings at once though. I want the script to use each string, one at a time, to be concatenated to the group string and then to be appended to out.